# rotate a image on the nose and eye axis with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I have the following image with eyes and noise points. The guy in the picture has a minimal tilt and I want to normalize this. I have mark the landmarks with dlib and so I can calculate the tilt.

Now, how can I rotate simply the whole image, that the guy is straight?
[image]

```
LEFT_EYE: [(274, 269), (286, 259), (302, 258), (317, 268), (302, 271), (286, 272)]
RIGHT_EYE : [(388, 264), (401, 254), (417, 252), (431, 261), (419, 265), (403, 265)]
NOSE: [(352, 257), (353, 278), (354, 297), (354, 319)]
```

As an idea, the nose points on the x axis are 352, 353, 354, 354. Theoretically if I make a matrix transformation, that change the all x points to 352, the noise will be straight in a line.

I think it can be done with a matrix transformation, and the noise or eye points as vector transformation. But I need an approach, how can this be solved.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with a rotation matrix. The concept is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do a linear fit to the nose points, and use the slope to find the angle.  To do this, switch x- and y-values so that straight up is an angle of 0 degrees (also, so you get a better fit when the nose is almost straight up to start).

```
# Nose points
nose =  np.array([(352, 257), (353, 278), (354, 297), (354, 319)])

# Linear fit with x- and y-values switched
m,b = np.polyfit(nose[:,1], nose[:,0], 1)

# Angle in radians
angle = np.arctan(m)
```

Next, you can use opencv to [get a rotation matrix](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#getrotationmatrix2d).  If the center of rotation doesn't matter, you can just rotate around the center of the image. But below I rotate it around the top of the nose so the points sit vertically along the x=352 line if you do want that.  Finally, use the rotation matrix to rotate the image with [`cv2.warpAffine`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine).

```
# Get rotation matrix
rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(tuple(nose[0]), -angle*180./np.pi, 1)

# Rotate image
dims = tuple(img.shape[:2][::-1])
rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(img, rot_mat, dims)
```

Here's the resulting image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have known the degrees of rotation (e.g., from 0 to 360 degrees).

The following function only does one thing: rotate the image without missing any pixels of the original input.

[image]

Parameters are (1) the original image; (2) the degrees of rotation.
Output should be the rotated image.

```
def rotate_bound(image, angle):
    # grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the
    # center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

    # grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))
```

The implementation is from a great blog "[Rotate image (correctly) with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/)". I believe you can find more details and useful learning there.

Have fun.